# SQL Server 2016(130) fail to convert datetime '18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016-express

I am new to SQL Server 2016(compatibility version 130). Getting error while converting one varchar column to datetime2. 
Simple try

```
select convert( datetime2, '18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM', 131)
```

As a workaround I even tried

```
select convert(datetime2, SUBSTRING('18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM',1,21)
      + SUBSTRING('18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM',29,2) , 131)
```

> Error message: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: You have a 2 digit year... make it a 4 digit and drop the 131 at the end. `select convert( datetime2, '2018-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM')` or use the correct one, like `select convert( datetime2, '18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM',11)`

Comment: If you can, find the person who used that format and smack them. Two year centuries, a twelve-hour clock *and* an absurd number of extra digits for the fractional seconds? That's... not fun to parse. There's always time to convert to the church of ISO 8601.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know specific culture[style] you could use simple trick to check it (`TRY_CONVERT`):

```
WITH cte AS (
  select r, '18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM' AS input,
     try_convert( datetime2, '18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM', r) AS result
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS r 
        FROM dbo.syscolumns s1,dbo.syscolumns s2) s
  WHERE r <= 255 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE result IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY r ASC;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3638698a337261c212eb6db1c87084ba)**

Then use correct r:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2, '18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM', 3 ) --or 2
```

Comment: Huh ... ,3  Had to delete mine when I saw this  +1

Comment: Interesting. I would have expected the time to be dropped, or for that to just not work, considering that the document says that `3` is `dd/mm/yy`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks the date format that you used is "Italian", so the following simple code will get you the answer.

select convert( datetime2, '18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM', 5)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the style tag you're providing and the date don't match. Style Tag `131` according to 
[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) uses the format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM`. Your date looks nothing like that.

None of the style tags on that page match the style you're using, so simple `CONVERT` isn't going to work.

Assuming you can't change your data's layout, this is one way, but it's messy:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(datetime2,REPLACE(LEFT('18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM',8),'-','/'),11),102),'.','-') + 'T' +
                         CONVERT(varchar(21),CONVERT(time,RIGHT('18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM',21))))
```

Edit: And some extra examples, and use against a table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (OddDate varchar(50));
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('18-04-14 04:17:48.000000000 PM'),
       ('18-03-31 12:58:45.000000000 AM'),
       ('18-02-24 12:58:45.000000000 PM'),
       ('17-01-04 07:59:59.000000000 AM');

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(datetime2,REPLACE(LEFT(S.OddDate,8),'-','/'),11),102),'.','-') + 'T' +
                         CONVERT(varchar(21),CONVERT(time,RIGHT(S.OddDate,21))))
FROM #Sample S;
GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Returns:

```
---------------------------
2018-04-14 16:17:48.0000000
2018-03-31 00:58:45.0000000
2018-02-24 12:58:45.0000000
2017-01-04 07:59:59.0000000
```